# Telerik WPF controls: what control can host multiple controls inside a pane

Tags: wpf, telerik

I've split the window into left and right panes using the docking splitter, panegroups, and panes. Each pane must host several controls:

```
LEFT PANE
FileDialog
ProgressBar
GridView

RIGHTPANE
checkbox + label
dropdown list
another dropdown list
button
GridView
another button
```

Multiple controls cannot be added directly to the pane. What (Telerik) container control should be placed in each of the panes to host their respective controls?

Answer (score 0):

Arrange the controls in the pane using any of the standard panel controls (Grid, StackPanel, Canvas, DockPanel etc).